# How to store data for mondrian queries?

Tags: java, olap, mondrian

I'm trying to understand how I should store data in order to query it with MDX queries processed by mondrian. I am having trouble storing data as i don't know if I should include redundancy in the data.

For example, I have facts for `YEAR_2017` and for each of its quarter ( `Q1_2017`, `Q2_2017`, `Q3_2017` and `Q4_2017`).

The measure value for `YEAR_2017` facts are indeed the sum of values for each quarter. To the same extent, I store `TOP_HIERARCHY` values and its `CHILD_HIERACHY` values, generating redundancy once more.

The result is, when I query `TOP_HIERARCHY` for `YEAR_2018`, I end up with a result that is the sum of every child value of my `TOP_HIERARCHY` and for each of them, the sum of every quarter and the value of the year.

In the end I end up with completely wrong results, so my question is, should I simply but values of childless hierarchies in the fact table ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't keep both the granular and aggregated data in the same table.

If your data aggregates correctly, then you should just keep the most atomic data values in the fact table. Mondrian takes care of aggregating the months into quarters, quarters into years, etc.

You would normally create a star schema: one fact table and several dimension tables.

Each dimension will have a column for each level of the hierarchy. So, your date dimension would have a primary key, `date_id`, then `year`, `quarter`, `month_number`, `month_name`, `day_of_month` and any other field you may want to add to allow drilling down.

Your fact table will have 1 column for each key to each dimension, then 1 column for each measure. An example would be `date_id`, `customer_id`, `product_id`, `quantity_sold`, `total_amount`.

The Mondrian schema will specify how to aggregate the measures (normally, `sum`), and issue the necessary SQL queries with the correct joins, group by and aggregations.

Comment: Thanks, I figured this out finally but for some reason the original cube used wrong values for aggregated fact values, therefore my confusion. Now we use the most atomic data values and after double checking with handmade SQL queries everything works fine !

Comment: I have a case where I need to store custom aggregations (e.g. the total of a YEAR is not the sum of its QUARTERs). Is it doable with mondrian ? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe add a “correction” fact table row so the totals match. But it’s not good practice to do so. The fact table should have only facts, and they’re either additive or they’re not.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this information. The thing we have people outside of the technical area who wish mondrian could do anything, thus I thought of bending it, but I get confirmations from multiple sources that this is a bad idea. Thanks.